# Class relationship between two given .cls file?

Tags: document-classes, lyx-layouts

The larger context of my question is about installing a document class in Lyx. I've done all the usual 'texhash' and 'reconfigure' thing, but just realize that I need to create a layout in Lyx for this `acmsmall` document class, which leads me to the following question.

According to [this](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts), I need to create a layout file like:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this      
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[acmsmall]{ACM Small}

# Read the definitions from article.layout
Input article.layout
```

However, I am not sure `acmsmall.cls` is a descendent of `article.cls`, or any other `.cls` file. Is this information embedded in `acmsmall.cls`? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find out whether a specific document class is loaded as base for another class is to view the source. You would usually find an entry like

```
\LoadClass[..]{article}
```

to imply that the `article` document class is loaded. Alternatively, when you load an unknown class, view the `.log` file (`Document`>`LaTeX Log`). It should be evident from viewing the entries whether or not `article.cls` is loaded. Here's a snapshot of a `.log` that *does* load the `article` document class:

[image]

From a browse of [`acmsmall.cls`](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/), it does *not* load `article`. Using this knowledge you can setup your LyX `.layout` file *without* `article` as base.

Note that this is not uncommon. That is, it is not necessary for any class to use the standard LaTeX classes as base. In fact, [many](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [do](http://ctan.org/pkg/amslatex) [not](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).