# Naming LyX layout appropriately

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I am continuing my question from [Class relationship between two given .cls file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42913/class-relationship-between-two-given-cls-file)

To use an custom document class one needs to create LyX layout named appropriately.

In my custom document class. I have code like this

```
\if@Synopsis 
    \LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\else
    \LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\fi
```

It is dynamically loading either the `article` or `report` class. So, in this case can anyone let me know how to name my LyX layout?

Answer (score 3):

You may have inherent difficulty adding this to LyX since you would need to set `\@Synopsis` to either `true` or `false` *before* your custom document class is loaded - something I don't think you have a hook into with LyX's interface. As far as I can see, there is no option to specify a condition for inputting a specific LyX `.layout`.